# Looking for dotnetcore specs

Tags: .net-core

I am transitioning from the old .net framework to dotnetcore 3.0 recently.

I've been trying to find the official specs for dotnetcore which describes its internals, type systems, il, etc. In .NET framework this is called the CLI partition (https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). This doc was last edited on 2012.

If dotnet core is a compliant implmentation of CLI (similar to .net framework), then I guess the old CLI spec is still the most up to date?
What about ecma doc for C# 8?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some interesting information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), which is a link you have probably found already.

It states in reference to [ECMA 335](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/dotnet-standards.md)

*There's no similar spec for the .NET Base Class Libraries (BCL) for .NET library implementations.*

In reference to a specification, Microsoft points to a standardized set of APIs, moderated by a feedback process using Github issues at [dotnet/standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard)

The Official Artifacts section of the document is interesting. It states:
*The official specification is a set of .cs files that define the APIs that are part of the standard.*

The see the official specification of the API, Microsoft refers us to the source code:

*The official specification is a set of .cs files that define the APIs that are part of the standard. The ref directory in the [dotnet/standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/src/netstandard/ref) repository in the [dotnet/standard repository](https://github.com/dotnet/standard) defines the .NET Standard APIs.*

To learn more about the internals about dotnet, you will end up in the implimenation details of the C# language. [An introduction is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction)

As there does not seem to be a definitive writen specification in one place, the answer seems to be "Read our source code!"